# combining results of 3 queries in one result

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

i have 3 queries and i want all result be in only one result using array_merge and array_unique.

here's the queries:

```
            $query1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM prereservation where '$arival' BETWEEN arrival and departure and room_id ='11' and status = 'active'");  
        while($rows1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query1)){
        echo $rows1['id']. " - ". $rows1['qty'];
        echo "<br />";
        }

        $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM prereservation where '$departure' BETWEEN arrival and departure and room_id ='11' and status = 'active'");
        while($rows2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query2)){
        echo $rows2['id']. " - ". $rows2['qty'];
        echo "<br />";
        }

        $query3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM prereservation where arrival > '$arival' and departure < '$departure' and room_id ='11' and status = 'active'");
        while($rows3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query3)){
        echo $rows3['id']. " - ". $rows3['qty'];
        echo "<br />";
        }

example result is:    
for       $rows1     |     $rows2     |     $rows3
        id  |  qty   |   id  |  qty   |   id  |  qty
       -----|--------|-------|--------|-------|------
        01  |   1    |   01  |   1    |   02  |   1
        03  |   1    |   02  |   1    |   03  |   1
        04  |   1    |   03  |   1    |   04  |   1
        08  |   1    |   05  |   1    |   05  |   1
```

i dont know if this is right?

```
$sample = array_unique(array_merge($rows1['id'], $rows2['id'], $rows3['id']))
```

i want to use array_merge and array_unique for id's of each results
so the final result for id's that will be left is

```
01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 08.
```

and for the next query all i want is the sum(qty) of those id's.
but i don't know how to write a query for this, here's my sample:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT sum(qty) FROM prereservation where id = $sample");

        while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query))
          {
          $total_qty = $rows['sum(qty)'];
          }
```

so the sum(qty) is equal to 6.
please correct my mistakes for coding, thanks guys...

**Finally i found the solution, here it is..**

```
$a = $p['id'];
        $query1 = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT id, SUM(qty)
        FROM prereservation 
        WHERE 
        (
            ( '$arival1' BETWEEN arrival AND departure ) OR 
            ( '$departure1' BETWEEN arrival AND departure ) OR 
            ( arrival > '$arival1' AND departure < '$departure1' )
        )
            AND room_id ='$a' 
            AND STATUS = 'active'");  
        while($rows1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query1)){
        $set1 = $rows1['SUM(qty)'];
        }   
        ?> 
        <select id="select" name="qty[]" style=" width:50px;" onchange="checkall()">
        <option value="0"></option>
        <? $counter = 1; ?>
        <? while ($counter <= ($p['qty']) - $set1){ ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $counter ?>"><?php echo $counter ?></option>
        <? $counter++;
        }?>
        </select>
```

**solution was made by combining all of your answers, thank you guys..**

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 1):

while not combine the three queries using `UNION ALL` in subquery and calculate their total `qty`?

```
SELECT SUM(qty)
FROM tableName
FROM
    (
        SELECT * 
        FROM prereservation 
        where ('$arival' BETWEEN arrival and departure) and 
                room_id ='11' and 
                status = 'active'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT * 
        FROM prereservation 
        where ('$departure' BETWEEN arrival and departure) and 
                room_id ='11' and 
                status = 'active'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT * 
        FROM prereservation 
        where (arrival > '$arival' and departure < '$departure') and 
                room_id ='11' and 
                status = 'active'
    ) a
GROUP BY colName
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine your 3 SQL statements into one using `OR` clause because you are basically `SELECT`ing `*` over same table for 3 different cases. That way you can be sure to have all unique results.

Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM prereservation where
(
(arrival > '$arival' and departure < '$departure')
or ('$departure' BETWEEN arrival and departure)
or ('$arival' BETWEEN arrival and departure)
) and room_id ='11' and status = 'active'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine all three queries into one query by using `select ... union select ...`:

```
$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM prereservation where '$arival' BETWEEN arrival and departure and room_id ='11' and status = 'active' union SELECT * FROM prereservation where '$departure' BETWEEN arrival and departure and room_id ='11' and status = 'active' union SELECT * FROM prereservation where arrival > '$arival' and departure < '$departure' and room_id ='11' and status = 'active'");
```

Then you don't need to merge multiple results into one.

An easier and less expensive way though, would be to merge the `where` clauses into one and use that:

```
select * from prereservation
where ('$arival' between arrival and departure
       or '$departure' between arrival and departure
       or arrival > '$arival' and departure < '$departure')
      and room_id ='11' and status = 'active'
```

Answer (score 0):

Better combine your 3 queries to 1

```
SELECT id, SUM(qty) as sumQty 
FROM prereservation 
WHERE 
(
    ( arival BETWEEN '$arrival' AND 'departure' ) OR 
    ( departure BETWEEN '$arrival' AND '$departure' ) OR 
    ( arrival > '$arival' AND departure < '$departure')
)
    AND room_id ='11' 
    AND status = 'active'
GROUP BY id
```

The you can `echo $rows3['id']. " - ". $rows3['sumQty'];`

Answer (score 0):

You should use a single query with OR between your conditions and use DISTINCT to make sure there are no duplicates. As for the last query:

```
"SELECT sum(qty) FROM prereservation where id = $sample GROUP BY id;"
```